# Is there a special character for docx that MS Word knows to make a word italics (using python-docx)

Tags: python, fonts, docx

I've setup a python38 script that reads a template docx file with styles set to paragraphs, and then replace the text with new string that I build up. But I now need to make some words italics inside the paragraph and I'm trying to avoid having to do a lot of rewriting to build the paragraphs differently.
So I was hoping there is another way...

Is there a special character I can use that MS Word will recognise and make a particular word italics?
For example, I have the following code:

```
for string in instructions.get_instructions()[instruction_key]:
    string = string.replace('<number_of_items>',str(no_of_items))
    string = string.replace('<item_name>', str(item_ref))
    string = string.replace('<front_end>', front_end_ref_formatted)
    string = string.replace('<back_end>', back_end_ref_formatted)
    string = string.replace('<address>',address)
    document.add_paragraph(string, style=style('SOW_Document_install_new_item'))
```

Is there something like

```
for string in instructions.get_instructions()[instruction_key]:
    string = string.replace('<<item_name> italics=True>', str(item_ref))
    document.add_paragraph(string, style=style('SOW_Document_install_new_item'))
```

Where MS Word will see that italics is True in the text? Similar to how `'\n'` means next line in a text file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [python-docx user guide](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart.html), italics are applied at a run level. All the text within a paragraph is contained in a sequence of one or more runs. So, it seems like you'd need to replace a run with a sequence runs in which the word(s) to be formatted comprised their own run, and then apply italics to that run.